# textAllCaps in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How do I achieve the same effect as `textAllCaps` in Jetpack Compose, I know that I can use `toUpperCase` method on the string itself to turn the string into uppercase. But I wonder is there a property that I can add to `Text` composable to visually turn the text into uppercase?

```kotlin
Text(
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name).toUpperCase(Locale.current)
)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's not such property, but you can create it by yourself:

```
@Composable
fun CapsText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    Text(
        text = text.uppercase(),
        modifier = modifier,
        color = color,
        fontSize = fontSize,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        lineHeight = lineHeight,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
        style = style,
    )
}
```

Comment: Hey @weston. there're two versions of `Text` composable: one that takes `String` and an other one that takes `AnnotatedString`. I don't think your edit makes sense, so I'm reverting it.

Answer (score 29):

```
Text(
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name).uppercase()
)
```

You can just add `.uppercase()` on the `stringResource`.
currently I'm using compose `1.2.0-beta03` version.

Comment: Not a good practice though, right? The function remains an algorithm even though it's time complexity is O(N). There is a discussion here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227070850

Comment: @HocineB yes you are right, I do not suggest using my answer on a big project.

Answer (score 10):

.toUpperCase(Locale.current) is deprecated and replaced with .uppercase()
example usage as below :

```
Text(
    text = ("any").uppercase()
)
```

This will render in UI as ANY

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Characters
        )
```

Comment: above doesn't work for me!

Comment: it works, but you can still make it small character from keyboard caps lock button

Answer (score 1):

You can always use capitalize function of String class. Alternatively, Text composable can also take [Annotated String](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) as an input, you can use [toUpperCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString#(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString).toUpperCase(androidx.compose.ui.text.intl.LocaleList)) function of AnnotatedString:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Sample() {
    Text(text = upperCased("Hello"))
}

@Composable
fun upperCased(input: String): AnnotatedString {
    return buildAnnotatedString {
        append(input)
//        You can also add styling here as below:
//        
//        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue)) {
//            append("John")
//        }
//        append("Doe")
//
//        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Red)) {
//            append("W")
//        }
//        append("orld")
    }.toUpperCase()
}
```

One benefit I see here is that you can avoid re-writing styles throughout the app.

Answer (score -2):

```
  Text(
                stringResource(id = R.string.main_widget)**.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())**,
                fontFamily = aeonikPro,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                color = ColorGraySecondary,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
```

Comment: I recommend you to add sentences to explain your code
For your code , you should add code style (Ctrl-K)