# Compose material androidx.compose.material.Typography AllCaps Missing?

Tags: material-design, android-jetpack-compose, typography

I am trying to customise Jetpack Compose

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
```

I could mimmic the complete XML  except for

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
```

**example**

```kotlin
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = ubuntu,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        letterSpacing = TextUnit(0.03125f, TextUnitType.Sp)
    ),
    h6 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = ubuntu,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 10.sp,
        letterSpacing = TextUnit(0.166666667f, TextUnitType.Sp)
    )
...
```

the parameters in androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle.kt I can manupilate is:

```kotlin
    val color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    val fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    val fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    val fontSynthesis: FontSynthesis? = null,
    val fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    val fontFeatureSettings: String? = null,
    val letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    val baselineShift: BaselineShift? = null,
    val textGeometricTransform: TextGeometricTransform? = null,
    val localeList: LocaleList? = null,
    val background: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    val shadow: Shadow? = null,
    val textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    val textDirection: TextDirection? = null,
    val lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    val textIndent: TextIndent? = null
```

However I do not see one that allow me to define **ALLCAPS**

Comment: Compose has no goal to copy all the functionality from the XML API. The maintainers decided that such a feature is unnecessary because it is easy to make your own element, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925822/textallcaps-in-jetpack-compose/68925978#68925978)

Comment: Yes, I saw that "Own element" a few times - I guess you are correct! I wonder how `androidx.compose.material3` is handeling it, even if!